# Wordpress WooCommerce get custom data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I need to get the product id, product variation id , and custom field text from each order. I have retrieved all except the custom field text input data, using:

```
 $product_description = get_post_meta($item['product_id'])->post_content
```

Actually crashed the site altogether whereas all other parameters work well.  See snippet below:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order($order_id)
{
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $myuser_id = (int)$order->user_id;
    $user_info = get_userdata($myuser_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
        $product_name = $item['name'];
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
        $product_description = get_post_meta($item['product_id'])->post_content
    }
    return $order_id;
}
```

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * 
 * @param int $post_id
 * @return string
 */
function get_the_content_by_id ( $post_id ) {
    $content_post = get_post ( $post_id );
    $content = $content_post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters ( 'the_content', $content );
    $content = str_replace ( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
    return $content;
}
```

Add this code in `function.php` and the use like this

`$product_description = get_the_content_by_id($item['product_id']);`

So your code will look like

```
 add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
    function custom_process_order($order_id) {
        $order = new WC_Order ( $order_id );
        $myuser_id = ( int ) $order->user_id;
        $user_info = get_userdata ( $myuser_id );
        $items = $order->get_items ();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {

            $product_name = $item ['name'];
            $product_id = $item ['product_id'];
            $product_variation_id = $item ['variation_id'];
            $product_description = get_the_content_by_id($item['product_id']);
        }
        return $order_id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `get_post_meta` wrongly. If you want to have **post_content** then you need to change your code to below which might work for you:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $myuser_id = (int)$order->user_id;
    $user_info = get_userdata($myuser_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $product_name = $item['name'];
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
        $product_description = get_post_field('post_content', $product_id);
    }
    return $order_id;
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thanks it still returned and empty set.

Comment: Have you tried checking by use of `print_r($product_description)`? Are you sure you get `$product_id` which is passed to the `get_post_field` function?

Comment: Yes Ive added a mail function that emails me all the values so the product_id is fine

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but for anyone that comes across this and still needs an answer:

To get a custom field you've created for the checkout page, for example, asking for the buyer's employer, you can retrieve the info with:

```
$employer = get_post_meta($order_id, "field_name", true);
```

Where the "field_name" is the meta_key in the wp_postmeta table.

This works for custom fields added to the product as well:

```
$custom_field = get_post_meta($product_id, "field_name", true);
```